# If A is $n \times n$ and only $v = 0$ for $Av = 0$, columns of $A$ are a basis for $\Bbb{R}^n$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I'm studying for my final and I came across this true or false question in the review:

If A is an $n \times n$ matrix and the only solution to $Av = 0$ is $v=0$, columns of A are a basis for $\Bbb{R}^n$.

I'm not sure how to discern the answer. I assume it has something to due with eigenvalues (and the relationship $Av = \lambda v$). I know that for $\lambda = 0$ in a matrix that means the null space is non trivial. If the only solution is $v = 0$, then that would mean $\lambda = 0$ is not an eigenvector of $A$. Does the answer come from that?

Comment: Do you know the rank-nullity theorem?

Comment: $rank(A) + dim(null(A)) = n$, correct?

Comment: Yes, so the linear function asociated to the matrix $A$ is inyective if and only if it is suryective. You can use that or the answers below.

Answer (score 2):

Suppose that the columns of $A$ did not form a basis on $\mathbb{R}^n$. Since the matrix has $n$ vectors, it must be that they are linearly dependent. As such, we can find a nonzero solution of $c_k$'s to

$$\sum_{k=1}^nc_k{\bf v_k}=0$$

where ${\bf v_k}$ are the columns of $A$. What does this mean about the vector $\bf c$ with entries $c_k$?

Comment: If they were linearly dependent , that would mean there is $c_1...c_k$ that are non zero that lead to the summation being zero. You may need to spell it out for me a bit more, I am having trouble applying this concept when it's a matrix multiplying a vector.

Answer (score 1):

Let columns of $A $ be denoted by $c_1,\dots,c_n $ and $v=[v_1, \dots ,v_n]$. Then $Av=v_1c_1+\dots +v_mc_n=0$ has only trivial solution $v=0$ iff $c_i's $ form a linearly independent set.